# Quantum Numbers and Light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, photons, solar-cells

I know how the quantum numbers can be applied to atomic and molecular orbitals, and that they have very similar nuclear interpretations, but how are these quantum numbers applied to light? I believe the n number is at least strongly correlated to the frequency of light... but there are three other quantum numbers I don't know about.

When I say n is correlated to the frequency I mean that when a photon of light is absorbed n is changed but I guess that is not exactly correct... n is changed if the energy is sufficient. I suppose ℓ and thus consequently m can be changed as well but as mentioned by Semoi spin is associated more in my mind at least with the internal orbital angular momentum of light though it seems I may be incorrect and that it is actually associated with the spin angular momentum.

What I was wondering was if there were other associations like this that I am unaware of. (I didn't mention the iOAM in my initial question because I was unsure and did not want to start anyone on the wrong path, and wanted some independent verification of that point anyway. {And it seems I was somewhat wrong!} Thank you Semoi and Emilio Pisanty for correcting me on that. - Does the [OAM][1] have any such associations with anything in orbitals?) I suppose the way I should think of this is what would be the quantum properties of a free electron. That was weirdly helpful. If I am incorrect in this assumption please let me know!

Comment: The quantum numbers you're referring to are the ones in the solution of a hydrogen atom, right? If so, what do they have to do with light? In what context?

Comment: Google "atomic selection rules" and you will find answers.

Comment: Are you asking how the frequency of the light emitted is related to changes in the quantum numbers $n$, $l$ and $m$?

Comment: To be honest I'm way more confused about what it is you're asking after the edit.

Comment: That said, regarding the relationship between atomic angular momentum and the spin and orbital angular momentum of light, the [Wikipedia article on selection rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule#Angular_momentum) might help settle the ideas in this question to an answerable state. Generally, both light OAM (the $\lambda$ in $E\lambda$ and $M\lambda$) and spin (polarization) determine the angular-momentum properties of the pairs of states that can be coupled by that given mode of radiation.

Answer (score 1):

A **photon** has the following quantum numbers:

- a spin $S=1$, which is associated with the [*polarization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light).
- Hence, it has a component of the spin along the quantization axis, $m_s$.

A **beam of light** has additionally

- an *orbital angular momentum* $L$, which is associated with the [spatial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_angular_momentum_of_light) of the E-field.
- Hence, it has a component of the orbital angular momentum along the quantization axis, $m_l$.

However, neither have a [principal quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_number) $n$.

Comment: Single photons can have orbital angular momentum just as much as light beams can - but it's unusual to work in situations where the *total* angular momentum is a meaningful quantum number.